# Why does my Python http server occasionally die silently?

Tags: python, http

I made a http server with python in my computer. Its function is to return the IP address and port of the visitor. In most cases, it works fine. Occasionally, however, it "dies silently" : I can see it in the process list, but I get no response to port 80.

```
import http.server
import json


class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response_str = json.dumps(
            {
                "ip": self.client_address[0],
                "port": self.client_address[1]
            },
            ensure_ascii=False
        )
        self.wfile.write(response_str.encode("utf-8"))


http.server.HTTPServer(("", 80), MyHandler).serve_forever()
```

When it works, access port 80 and I can get a reply:

```
{"ip": "202.112.51.4", "port": 12974}
```

But sometimes it dies silently, then I can't access the port 80.
However, I find it is still in the process list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd5G0.png)

I have tried many times.

Comment: You get log messages, don't you?  What do they say?